# Match URL with alphanumeric, dash & underscore characters?

Tags: php, regex

How can I match the following function with the segment in the middle `("/(\w+)\")` to allow URL characters like alphanumerics & `_.-`  ?

```
if(preg_match('/^\/segment1\/(\w+)\/segment2/', '/segment1/aAbB0123.-_Z/segment2', $match)) {                       
    print_r($match);
    /*
    * Array
    (
        [0] => /segment1/s/segment2
        [1] => aAbB0123.-_Z
    )
    *
}
```

Comment: Looking at it from another angle... is `[^/]` not what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one other issue with your pattern, it's requiring a forward slash at the end, whereas your input does not have one.  I wouldn't even make it optional, just leave it out altogether, you can't get more optional than that.

Is your goal here to Validate, or to Capture that middle segment?  I'm assuming capture since in your example there would be no other reason to have a sub-expression.  Giving a couple exact input examples and what you actually require would be best.

So, you have a few options.

Super lazy:

```
segment1/(.*?)/segment2
```

One Sub-Segment, also Super lazy:

```
segment1/([^/]+)/segment2
```

Exact Requirements (Find out what you want in a URL, I'm pretty sure some of those characters you listed aren't allowed in a URL, just in the Querystring):

```
segment1/([-\w&.%=#]+)/segment2
```

Allow Multiple Segments, Lazy:

```
segment1/((?:[^/]+/?)+)/segment2
```

Allow Multiple Segments, Exact Requirements:

```
segment1/((?:[-\w&.%=#]+/?)+)/segment2
```

Depending on your settings, you may need to escape some things.